# How to convert .caf file to .mp3 file using php?

Tags: php

I have created one webservice using php which upload audio file from IOS device to server.audio file gets uploaded as .caf format which is not supported by server so is there any way to convert .caf file to .mp3 or .wav file?

I want to create PHP script which will convert .caf file to .mp3 file any idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: wait. somebody did that already. See: http://www.techisky.com/how-to/convert-caf-file-to-mp3.html

Comment: Thanks Shivan,But i want php script to do this.my webservice is running in parallel plesk and it does not support .caf file.it only support .mp3 file

Answer (score 2):

[Core Audio Format (.caf)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio_Format) is a audio file container developed by Apple for audio files. A .caf file can contains different audio file formats just like .mov container for different video formats.

So, changing the format from .CAF to .MP3 through Program is a difficult task but not impossible thing. I think you can use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) to change the format from CAF to MP3, just download the latest build or create your own are use the following command:

```
FFMPEG -i song.caf song.mp3
```

I haven't tried thing thing at all but think it will work. There is also a Perl Script available known as [PACPL](http://pacpl.sourceforge.net/) through which can be done as:

```
shell_exec("pacpl input.caf -to mp3");
```

You may or may not need to reconfigure the permissions or use sudo in there depending on the host server config.

.caf is just a container format, what's inside can vary, although the vast majority of the time it's going to be PCM uncompressed audio. This could actually be what was tripping Audacity and other programs up, as they were expecting PCM and what is inside the .caf  is something else, like AAC. I've seen something similar happen with WAV files (which is also a container format, but has PCM audio in it most of the time).

Comment: Thanks. i have search on google about shell_exec("pacpl input.caf -to mp3"); but i didn't find where to use shell_exec("pacpl input.caf -to mp3"); in php code.do u have any idea about where i have to use shell_exec("pacpl input.caf -to mp3"); in php code?